# When making a request as an account that does not have a mailbox, you must specify the mailbox primary SMTP address for any distinguished folder Ids

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I am using  `EWS java api`. We Dont have outlook configuration for some group email ids. we are using browser to check emails coming to those ids with credentials. and we use browser URL as

https://outlook.abc.met/owa/Contractsatxxxx.com

Urls are end with email ids.

When I tried to read emails coming to these email ids getting below error.

> ERROR:
>   ----------------------------------------- microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceResponseException:
>   The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
                ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(userName, password);
                service.setCredentials(credentials);
                service.setUrl(new URI(hostUrl));

Folder rootfolder = Folder.bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot);
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm facing a similar problem now.